# Sustituir/sumar estilo en línea y less sin !important

Tags: css, angular, telerik, less

Estoy utilizando Kendo Telerik con Angular, por lo que, para crear ventanas o modales, se utilizan las `kendo window`. El diseño de dichas ventanas es global y puede haber una o más en cada vista (teniendo más de 400 a día de hoy y subiendo).

Para el posicionamiento (y el estilo en general) se utiliza Less, pero hay un problema y es que Kendo utiliza estilo en línea en la misma ventana al crearla para posicionarla, creando el HTML de la siguiente forma:

```
<kendo-window _ngcontent-gon-c18="" tabindex="0" class="k-widget k-window k-window-wrapper ng-star-inserted" dir="ltr" style="min-width: 120px; min-height: 100px; position: absolute; z-index: 10002; top: 230.2px; left: 354px;"></kendo-window>
```

Para posicionar las ventanas donde queremos, la única forma que encontré fue sustituyendo este estilo en línea con `!important`, sé que su uso está desaconsejado y, de hecho, no me gusta usarlo, pero no conozco otra forma de sustituir este estilo sin modificar todas las llamadas.

La cuestión está en que estas ventanas se pueden mover (`drag and drop`), siendo algo automático que hace Kendo, para ello modifica el atributo `top` que pone en línea por los píxeles que correspondan.

En mi Less tengo lo siguiente:

```
.k-window {
   position: fixed!important;
   top: 20px!important;
}
```

Al tener el `top` puesto de esa manera, por mucho que lo intente, la ventana no se mueve verticalmente (pues su posición siempre está machacada por mi estilo).

Mi pregunta es: ¿Habría alguna forma de obtener el `top` del estilo en línea y sumarlo al `top` del estilo en el Less sin tener que hacer una función por ventana? Tampoco me gustaría tener que ponerle a todas ventanas alguna llamada a una función general pues, como he dicho, son muchísimas ventanas y en cuanto se nos olvide en una dará muchos problemas hasta que encontremos el error...

Comment: Prueba a ponerle un selector mas especifico sin el `!important`. Puedes mirar que selector se le aplica en el navegador y usar el mismo, si tu  selector se aplica el último será este el que se aplique. Si no, puedes hacerlo mas especifico aun.

Comment: @x3k_js los estilos aplicados están en línea, aunque utilizara un selector muy específico (tipo con identificador o similar) seguiría utilizando el que está en línea a no ser que utilice el `!important` ...